# Guava Cache - maximumSize - Eviction (LRU or most often)

Tags: caching, guava

I am planning to use Guava Cache in my application. Some of the **[K, V]** pairs that are accessed are statistically >> than others and should be available in the cache essentially always.

According to the spec of [Sized Based Eviction](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained#Size-based_Eviction)

> If your cache should not grow beyond a certain size, just use
>   CacheBuilder.maximumSize(long). The cache will try to evict entries
>   that haven't been used recently or very often

I am trying to understand the **very often** part. Can I assume - for a cache of `maximumSize = 100`, if `Key_A` is accessed `10000` times and immediately post that there are `100` put calls, the `Key_A` would still be present in the cache? Basic unit test that I carried out doesn't seem to confirm this fact. *Any thoughts?*

```
public class CacheHelper
{
    private Cache<String, String> cache;
    public CacheHelper()
    {
        cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder().maximumSize(10).concurrencyLevel(1).build();
    }

    public String fetchVal(String key)
    {
        String val = cache.getIfPresent(key);
        return val;
    }

    public void putVal(String key, String val)
    {
        cache.put(key, val);
    }
}
```

Test

```
public class CacheTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        CacheHelper cacheHelper = new CacheHelper();
        cacheHelper.putVal("0", "0");
        for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            cacheHelper.fetchVal("0");
        }
        System.out.println(cacheHelper.fetchVal("0"));
        for(int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
        {
            String key = "" + i;
            cacheHelper.putVal(key, key);
        }
        System.out.println(cacheHelper.fetchVal("0"));  // Still returns NULL - "most often not being used?"
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Per my understating [Guava Cache](http://codingjunkie.net/google-guava-cache/) uses LRU as default eviction policy

In your case entry for key "0" became oldest value when you added 10 new values and hence oldest value evicted as cache reached to its max-size.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the guava spec says "very often **or recently**" and in your case, 1 to 10 key are more recents than 0 key. 
That's why 0 key have gone.

Try using a cache loader if performance is important for you. Thanks to the loader, guava can determine the delay for loading values and keep in memory most "usefull" items.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the intention of this, but setting maximumSize causes entries to be immediately ejected from the cache. This code:

```
void evictEntries(ReferenceEntry<K, V> newest) {
  if (!map.evictsBySize()) {
    return;
  }

  drainRecencyQueue();

  // If the newest entry by itself is too heavy for the segment, don't bother evicting
  // anything else, just that
  if (newest.getValueReference().getWeight() > maxSegmentWeight) {
    if (!removeEntry(newest, newest.getHash(), RemovalCause.SIZE)) {
      throw new AssertionError();
    }
  }

  while (totalWeight > maxSegmentWeight) {
    ReferenceEntry<K, V> e = getNextEvictable();
    if (!removeEntry(e, e.getHash(), RemovalCause.SIZE)) {
      throw new AssertionError();
    }
  }
}
```

The entry's weight is 1 which is greater than the maxSegmentWeight of 0 so it immediately removes the entry.